# How to inject dependency into JerseyTest?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi, jersey-2.0, jersey-test-framework

I want to inject `MyService` directly into my JerseyTest using CDI. Is it possible? `MyService` is succcefull injected into `MyResource` but I get NullPointerException when I try to access it from MyJerseyTest.

```java
public class MyResourceTest extends JerseyTest {

  @Inject
  MyService myService;

  private Weld weld;

  @Override
  protected Application configure() {
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty("org.jboss.weld.se.archive.isolation", "false");

    weld = new Weld();
    weld.initialize();

    return new ResourceConfig(MyResource.class);
  }

  @Override
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    weld.shutdown();
    super.tearDown();
  }

  @Test
  public void testGetPersonsCount() {
    myService.doSomething();  // NullPointerException here

    // ...

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to provide an instance of `org.junit.runner.Runner` where you will do the weld initialization. This runner should also be responsible for providing an instance of your Test class with necessary dependencies injected. An example is shown below

```
public class WeldJUnit4Runner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {  

private final Class<?> clazz;  
private final Weld weld;  
private final WeldContainer container;  

public WeldJUnit4Runner(final Class<Object> clazz) throws InitializationError {  
    super(clazz);  
    this.clazz = clazz;  
    // Do weld initialization here. You should remove your weld initialization code from your Test class.
    this.weld = new Weld();  
    this.container = weld.initialize();  
}  

@Override  
protected Object createTest() throws Exception {  
    return container.instance().select(clazz).get();    
}  
}
```

And your Test class should be annotated with `@RunWith(WeldJUnit4Runner.class)` as shown below.

```
@RunWith(WeldJUnit4Runner.class)
public class MyResourceTest extends JerseyTest {

@Inject
MyService myService;

  // Test Methods follow
}
```